# Records Login Entries and Session State

Tags: php, session, authentication, state, record

How can I record the login entries and session state? I've search for source codes and ideas but I can't understand some of it. I want to ask a simple code through PHP. I have a code that can login user but does not need MySql database, and I want an idea how to RECORD LOGIN ENTRIES AND SESSION STATE connecting my PHP Login code. Or if you have other option code that need MySql database.

Here's the code:

"CONFIG.PHP"

```
<?php
$user = "admin";
$pass = "password";
?>
```

"INDEX.PHP"

```
<?php
include("config.php");

// Check form if is submited
if(isSet($_POST['trimite'])) {
// Check if user is equal with username and  password from config.php
if($_POST['user'] != $user || $_POST['pass'] != $pass) {
echo "Sorry, your data is invalid";
} else {
// Open the session for store user logged
session_start();
// Setting the session
$_SESSION['logat'] = "da";
// Redirecting user to admin page if is logged
Header('Location: admin.php');
}
} else {
// Form
echo '<form action="" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit" name="trimite">
</form>';
}
?>
```

"ADMIN.PHP"

```
<?php
include("config.php");
// Start session
session_start();

// Check if user is logged and existing session
if(isset($_SESSION['logat'])) {
// Content for user logged
echo "Welcome ".$user." :) - <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
} else {
// Redirecting to login page
Header("Location: ./");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always put `session_start()` as the very first statement after `<?php`

It is okay to run session_start() even if the user is not logged in. `session_start()` should be the first statement.

Note that the `header()` command requires a lowercase `h` (not `Header` - that is wrong).

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("config.php");

    // Check form if is submited
    if( isSet($_POST['user']) ) {
        // Check if user is equal with username and  password from config.php
        if($_POST['user'] != $user || $_POST['pass'] != $pass) {
            echo "Sorry, your data is invalid";
        } else {
            // Open the session for store user logged
            // Setting the session
            $_SESSION['logat'] = "da";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
            // Redirecting user to admin page if is logged
            header('Location: admin.php');
        }
    } else {
        // Form
        $out = '
            <form action="" method="post">
                Username: <input type="text" name="user">
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
                <input type="submit" name="trimite">
            </form>
        ';
        echo $out;
    }
?>
```

**admin.php** -- Here is how to reference/use the username session variable:

```
<?php
    // Start session
    session_start();

    include("config.php");

    // Check if user is logged and existing session
    if(isset($_SESSION['logat'])) {
        // Content for user logged
        echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']." :) - <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    } else {
        // Redirecting to login page
        header("Location: ./");
    }
?>
```

---

Note that `header` can only be used if no data has been sent to the DOM yet. Sometimes that is very difficult to prevent. Here is an HTML tag that allows you to redirect to another page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com">
```

The number zero (before `url=` means the number of seconds to wait before redirecting the page.

Comment: Where will I put the <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com"> ?

Comment: It is HTML - so you can put it in your HTML code (anywhere you can put, for example, any other HTML tag), or you could echo it in a PHP code block: `echo "<meta http-etc etc>";`  Test it out, experiment with it.  Note that many people will tell you NOT to use this instruction, but (as with anything) being cautious and learning as much as you can allows you to do many things. "Everyone" is not always right. :)

Comment: How to record the log in entries and session state of the user? The user can now log in but I still need to have a code that will record the login entries of the user after he/she logged out. What is session state? does the session_start() a session state code?